# Find the $9$ subgroups of $S_4$ such that no group on your list is isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I know that for a group to be Isomorphic It has to have the same order. So I started by trying to find a subgroup of each possible order (that divides the size of the original group) but I realized that it would take me forever if I tried to do it numerically. But I cant see any other way to do it.

Comment: The way the title is written, this looks like a homework problem.  Writing a question like a homework problem may cause it to not be well-received.

Comment: In this type of problem (at least for small groups), it is usually best to try experimenting with generators, i.e., pick a few elements of $S_4$ and see what group they generate.

Comment: It is a question from an exercise sheet yes, I am going over it for revision.It has not been set as "homework"  However there must be a more practical way then trying to list out every possible group and checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to start listing generators until you run out of groups.

Trivial/improper subgroups:

- $\{0\}$
- $S_4$.

Subgroups generated by one element:

- $\langle (12)\rangle\simeq\mathbb{Z}/2$ (all transpositions generate this group)
- $\langle (123)\rangle\simeq\mathbb{Z}/3$ (all triples generate this group)
- $\langle (1234)\rangle\simeq\mathbb{Z}/4$

Subgroups generated by two elements:

- $\langle(12),(34)\rangle\simeq(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$ (all disjoint pairs of transpositions generate this group).
- $\langle (12),(123)\rangle\simeq S_3$ (its support is on the set $\{1,2,3\}$, so this group is a subgroup of $S_3$).
- $\langle (13),(1234)\rangle\simeq D_4$.  I find this one the hardest to spot, but the two elements listed above have the relations for $D_4$.

Special subgroups (some generated by two elements):

- $A_4$

Note also that $\langle (12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle$ form a normal subgroup isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$.